# how to store std::ratio in an std::unordered_map STL container at runtime

Tags: c++

Is it possible to store `std::ratio` type inside an STL container at runtime. I am trying to solve this problem https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-pairs-of-interchangeable-rectangles/ by using an `std::unordered_map<std::ratio, int>` STL container type.

Comment: please describe the question. not link.

Comment: Numerator and denominator of `std::ratio` should be compile time value...

Comment: Ratio uses template parameters.  If that doesn't work for you, just write your own ratio struct that stores the values as member variables.

Comment: `std::ratio` is meant to define ratios that are known at compile-time, such as the ratio between physical units like inches to feet, or seconds to hours.  It is not meant to work with runtime values.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the suggestion. I think I can use `operator=` operator overloading on the struct you suggested to check for equality.

Comment: @Harry That's a good start. You also need a hash function for the struct to be able to use it as a key in your `unordered_map`

Comment: @Harry If you have access to C++20, all you need is `struct ratio{ size_t numerator; size_t denominator; friend auto operator<=>(const ratio&, const ratio&) = default; };`

Comment: `std::ratio` is not a type it is just a template, for example `std::ratio<1,1>` is one, but it isnt very useful to have more than one object of it. They are all the same

Comment: @NathanOliver: Don't we want `ratio{2, 4} == ratio{1, 2}`, so default is not what we expect?

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh yeah, that wouldn't work.  It would also need a constructor that reduces the  fraction

Comment: @NathanOliver I think no need to reduce, just `return (numerator * other.denominator == denominator * other.numerator);` is sufficient.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Do you think it's better to use `std::map` instead of `std::unordered_map`? Because writing own hash function is a very tedious thing to do, I feel.

Comment: It depends. If _half_ the word size of `size_t` for the numerator and denominator is enough precision for you, writing a hash becomes really easy. Just bitshift the numerator up and binary OR with the denominator. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/1aezb1do4)

Comment: @Harry Oh, and since I used `std::gcd` in the example, `operator==` could be made simpler than I did it. `return lhs.numerator == rhs.numerator && lhs.denominator == rhs.denominator;` would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

No.

`std::ratio<U,V>` is a template that represents ratios *as types* for use at compile time. The numerator and denominators are compile time constants.

To put something in a hash table etc. at run time you would need some type that represents ratios as values. [Boost has a rational numbers library for example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/rational/rational.html).